# Animate a UIButton into place from off screen when app loads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, animation

I am having some issues with some animation stuff in an iPad application. I have four UIButtons that are on the screen when the app launches.

I basically want the app to load and the four buttons to animate into view one at a time from the top of the screen into place.

I have the following which kind of animates it but I am struggling with it.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGPoint newLeftCenter = CGPointMake( 15.0f + myCocoButton.frame.size.width / 2.0f, myCocoButton.center.y);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0f];
    myCocoButton.center = newLeftCenter;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

The current code that I have does animate the button but not in the way I want. I can't get my head around how to actually place it exactly where I want it.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now?

Comment: It doesn't do exactly what I want. I have to place the button off the view in IB and I can't get my head around having it place exactly where I want it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written a blog post about this subject: http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/07/01/iphone-dev-performing-sequential-uiview-animations/

and I have a sample project there.

You can just chain the animations where when one finishes it calls the function of the next animation. Can you be more specific about the exact issues you are having?

Comment: The issue I am having it that I can't get the button to finally rest where I want it on the screen. Plus, I have to set the button in IB off the screen so that it comes into view. Im sure there must be a 'proper' wayy of doing it. Ill read your link.

Comment: The way I like to set something off the screen is in code so you don't have to manage a messy IB file. So just keep the button outside of the view if you want and then in your "viewDidLoad" you can do something like:

Comment: [self.view addSubView: yourbutton]; yourbutton.frame = CGRectMake(100, -100, yourbutton.frame.size.width, yourbutton.frame.size.height);

Comment: I'd also recommend manipulating your button's frame rather than the center. This is just my preference but I find it easier to deal with the top left corner of the button when dealing with absolute values.

Comment: Yes I agree with that. Someone mentioned using the center which is why I was using it that way. However, the top left is easier for my little brain to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

In your storyboard, lay out your buttons in their final positions.

In `viewWillAppear:`, save the location of each button and move the button off-screen:

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    CGPoint _button0TrueCenter;
    CGPoint _button1TrueCenter;
    CGPoint _button2TrueCenter;
    CGPoint _button3TrueCenter;
}

static void moveButtonAndSaveCenter(UIButton *button, CGPoint offscreenCenter, CGPoint *trueCenter) {
    *trueCenter = button.center;
    button.center = offscreenCenter;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (animated) {
        moveButtonAndSaveCenter(self.button0, CGPointMake(-100, 100), &_button0TrueCenter);
        moveButtonAndSaveCenter(self.button1, CGPointMake(420, 100), &_button1TrueCenter);
        moveButtonAndSaveCenter(self.button2, CGPointMake(-100, 200), &_button2TrueCenter);
        moveButtonAndSaveCenter(self.button3, CGPointMake(420, 200), &_button3TrueCenter);
    }
}
```

Then in `viewDidAppear:`, animate them back to their original locations:

```
static void animateButton(UIButton *button, CGPoint newCenter, NSTimeInterval delay) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.25 delay:delay options:0 animations:^{
        button.center = newCenter;
    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (animated) {
        animateButton(self.button0, _button0TrueCenter, 0);
        animateButton(self.button1, _button1TrueCenter, 0.2);
        animateButton(self.button2, _button2TrueCenter, 0.4);
        animateButton(self.button3, _button3TrueCenter, 0.6);
    }
}
```

Comment: hhhmm, I implemented all of that but when the app loads the button just stays in exact same place as it is originally placed through Storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your buttons in an array, you could do something like this (your items should be in the correct end positions in the nib)

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.f, -200.f); 

    [self.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

       button.transform = transform; // This translates the view's off the top of the screen

       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f
                             delay:0.25f * idx
                           options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut            // No point doing easeIn as the objects are offscreen anyway
                        animations:^{
                            button.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                      } completion:nil];

       }];
}
```

This will animate every time. You may need to add an ivar to stop this happening and just set it to YES after this has run once. The problem I found when I was just messing around is that when it was calling `viewDidAppear:` `animated` was `NO` on first load, so I couldn't use that BOOL as a check